# jQuery Ajax not calling webmethod after url rewriting

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

My jQuery AJAX function is not calling my webmethod. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Search.aspx/GetCustomers",
    data: '{pageIndex:' + pageIndex + ',searchText:"' + $('#HiddenField1').val() + '",SearchBy:"' + $('#ddlSelectProfile').val() + '"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

```csharp
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCustomers(int pageIndex, string searchText, string SearchBy)
{
    return GetCustomersData(pageIndex,searchText, SearchBy ).GetXml();
}
```

and in web.config

```
<rewrite url="~/Search/(.+)-(.+).html" to="~/Search.aspx?MyTitleId=$1&amp;page=$2" processing="stop" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Web Forms, this challenge arises when links that look like those used for web methods, e.g. "/WebPageName.aspx/WebMethodName", are not exempted in URL rewrite rules set up for removing file extensions (e.g. to remove ".aspx"). So, the following condition must be added to the URL rewrite rule and this can look like...

```
<rule name="removeAspxExtension" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)\.aspx" />
    <conditions>
        <!--This is the condition to be added.-->
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="(.*)\.aspx/(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Also, if RegisterRoutes() is being used in RouteConfig.cs, the following lines (and all that aren't specific enough such that they could affect links that look like "/WebPageName.aspx/WebMethodName") must be commented out too, as follows...

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // The commented code lines...
    //routes.MapRoute(
    //    name: "Default",
    //    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    //);
}
```

Now, when a web method is accessed from the client-side, e.g. by using jQuery Ajax, things should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript change  "url: "Search.aspx/GetCustomers"" to "url: "Search/GetCustomers"," you are fobidding the access to *.aspx with this rule ;)

Answer (score -2):

url: "Search.aspx/GetCustomers" => url: "/Search.aspx/GetCustomers".

Add "/" to